# C++ Qt - How can (virtual) QWidget points to its children?

Tags: qt, qwidget

I am trying to change the border of a QFrame. BUT.

There is a Window::ui, inside of which there is a class inheriting from QWidget. 
In that class, there is a QFrame, set with a vertical Layout, which holds 2 other QFrame and do their QFrame business.
Now, this structure is repeated a lot in Window::ui, so I simply added it to a vertical layout named kingdom_decks.

So far, so good.

Let's say, I want to select one of those element. To mark the selection, I want to change the border, from black to red, or just make it thicker. With a QFrame, very easy. BUT

My event handler is a slot in Window::ui. `ui` goes to kingdom_decks layout, and go to the item selected. itemAt retourn a QLayoutItem, that I can cast as QWidget with widget()... but then?

```
ui->kingdom_decks->itemAt(idx_prev)->widget()
```

I tried unsuccessfully

```
 ui->kingdom_decks->itemAt(idx_prev)->widget()->childAt(0,0)
```

I believe it failed because there is a Qframe in a Layout, instead of a geometry form with real coordonates, or maybe I didn't go deep enough?

Anyway, thank you very much in advance for any ideas on that! Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**

Code for window.cpp

```
    #include "window.h"
    #include "ui_window.h"


    Window::Window(Game_state * p, Card_generator * d, QWidget *parent) :
        QDialog(parent),
        ui(new Ui::Window)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);

        /*Stuff happen here*/

        /* Display cards*/
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){

                /*Add widget to layout*/
                ui->kingdom_decks->addWidget(new Cards_kingdom(decks->decks_kingdom[i]),0,i);

                /*Connect widget to map*/
                connect(ui->kingdom_decks->itemAt(i)->widget(), SIGNAL(mousePressEvent()), signal_mapper, SLOT(map()));

                /*Map widget and data*/
                signal_mapper->setMapping(ui->kingdom_decks->itemAt(i)->widget(), i);
}

        /* Action "Select cards" */
        connect(signal_mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(card_kingdom_selected(int)));


    }

    Window::~Window()
    {
        delete ui;
    }


    /*Implementation of SLOT*/

    void Window::card_kingdom_selected(int idx){

    /*...*/
    //?????????????? What to do here???????????
    //ui->findChild<QLabel *>("img");
    //ui->kingdom_decks->itemAt(idx)->widget()->????;
    }
```

So what happen here is that I have a layout kingdom_decks, in which I loop to add a widget Cards_kingdom, overloading the function addWidget.

```
ui->kingdom_decks->addWidget(new Cards_kingdom(decks->decks_kingdom[i]),0,i);
```

This Object Cards_kingdom is a class, such that:

cards_kingdom.h :

```
class Cards_kingdom : public QWidget {

public:
    Cards_kingdom(Deck_kingdom * input_deck);    /* Constructor  */
    bool isSelected();
    QLabel * get_img();
/*
 * Price and Counter are display in the same label, then are wrapped with Icon in a vertical layout, inside a frame.
 */
private:
    QLabel       *img;       /* Icon         */
    QLabel       *info;      /* Nb Cards left*/
    QVBoxLayout  *layout;    /* Layout       */
    QFrame       *pack;      /* Frame        */
    Deck_kingdom *deck;      /* Type Deck    */
    bool select;
};
```

In window.cpp, i try to retrieve the `QLabel * img`, to put a border on this image, such that the user sees that it has been selected.

To answer to @Nicholas Smith, how can findChild, find the exact instanciation of `Card_kingdom`?

EDIT:

OK, I could change my architecture to something like this:

Create a vector of Cards_kingdom * vec

In the for loop,
   vec.push_back(new Card_kingdom *);
   ui->layout->addWIdget(vec[i])

So now, I think that would work, because layout is holding a pointer to my widget, so I pass by reference, therefore, if I change something in my object, it will appear in the GUI even if I didn't pass by there...

Right? :)

Comment: It's somewhat difficult to diagnose this problem without seeing your UI.  Also, if you're not sure of what type of widget you have retrieved from the layout item, consider printing out its class name (i.e., ui->kingdom_decks->itemAt(idx_prev)->widget()->metaObject()->className() ).

Comment: I tried it and it helped me a lot figuring out what was going on. I was able to change my architecture accordingly, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fun thing with Qt is layouts can become nests and layers and mazes, but I've just had this exact issue with a different twist, I'd personally go for something along the lines of `ui->findChild<QFrame *>("frameObjectName")` (if you've created QFrame as pointer, if not just drop the *) and access it from there. You'll need to make sure you have an object name filled it for the frame, but that's not too hard and has other benefits.

Comment: OK - but what if there is several instances of my object?
I am going to post some more code.

Comment: I posted and commented the part of code we are discussing. I wonder if itemAt(idx) would have findChild.
itemAt(idx) returns a QLayoutItem, so does QLayoutItem inherite from QObject... (just thinking at loud, please, tell me if I am moving in the right direction, for self-help)

If I read the doc correclty, QObject is the base of every object in Qt... :)

Comment: Something like `ui->kingdom_decks->itemAt(idx_prev)->findChild<QLabel *>("img")->setLineWidth(10);`

Comment: No, it does not work. The compiler tells me that QLayoutItem has no member  "findChild".

Comment: OK it works (see pseudo code edited in my msg), thanks a lot, your comment helped me figured a new architecture :)